# Possible to do more than one PageBlob operation in a single call? (many GETs or PUTs)

Tags: http, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have clients accessing Azure storage on a high latency connection, and it appears that the main reason for the slowness is the latency between each call.

The following happens several hundred times per user

Get flat directory listing 
Get the pages of the blobs that are listed 
Request the data in the pages
The application is taking advantage of the "sparse" nature of the PageBlob, and the small allocation units of 512 bytes, but that has a side effect of creating too many transactions.

Can I batch together several "Get Page Range" or "Get Page Blob" requests for objects with different names, like this in the same HTTP request:

```
 GET /containerName/Hourly/2012/01/01/02

 GET /containerName/Hourly/2012/01/01/03

 GET /containerName/Hourly/2012/01/01/04

 GET /containerName/Hourly/2012/01/01/05
```

or the same question goes for similar operations with PUT

Answer (score 0):

You could place your own service between you and azure storage, then you could combine several things in a single operation. However, this may not be a good idea.

It may be better to leave the calls as separate operations, but do them asynchronously and in parallel.

Have a look at this link for an example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2011/05/30/asynchronous-parallel-block-blob-transfers-with-progress-change-notification.aspx